# Laravel show return data by id null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The function `show()` in the TopModelController is returning null data when I try to open the details page.
It is falling on `if` test which shows TOP MODEL DETAILS NOT EXIST

## TopModelController

```
public function show(TopModelDetails $topModelDetails)
{
   $topModelDetails = DB::table("top_model_details as tmd")
        ->select(
            "tmd.id", "tmp.professional_name", "tmd.weight", "tmd.height",
            "tmd.body_type", "tmd.booty_type", "tmd.bust_type", "tmd.bust_size",
            "tmd.eye_color", "tmd.hair_color", "tmd.languages",
            "tmd.tattoed", "tmp.is_active"
         )
        ->join("top_model_profile as tmp", "tmp.id", "=", "tmd.escort_id")
        ->where("tmp.id", $topModelDetails->id)
        ->first();

       if( empty($topModelDetails) ) {
            return "<h1> The TOP MODEl DETAILS not exist. </h1>";
       }

       return view('admin.top_model_details.show')->with('md', $topModelDetails);
}
```

## TopModel model

```
class TopModelDetails extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;

  /**
    * The table name
  */
  protected $table = 'top_model_details';

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
  * @var array
 */
  protected $fillable = [
      'top_model_id', 'weight', 'height', 'body_type', 'booty_type',
      'bust_type', 'bust_size', 'eye_color', 'hair_color','languages'
  ];
}
```

Comment: Double check if you imported the model in your controller and also check the namespace of your model.

Comment: Si, I'm importing in both classes. Look: Controller (use App\Models\TopModelDetails;) Model (namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;)

Comment: What do you see if you add dd($topModelDetails); above if statement?

Comment: brings the data contained in the table 'top_model_details'

Comment: make sure your route looks something like this Route::get('your_page/{topModelDetails}', [TopModelController::class,  'show']); --- this variable "$topModelDetails" from "show(TopModelDetails $topModelDetails)" has to match what you name it in the route! {topModelDetails}

Comment: Route::resource('model-details', ModelDetailsController::class);